# resource-ref in Maven-generated application descriptor

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, ear

I'm using Maven's [ear plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin) to generate a Java EE 7 EAR file of my project for me, and the components will need to use a Datasource. As I understand it, the portable way to do this is to use a <resource-ref> element in my EAR's application descriptor. Can I get Maven to generate an EAR with an app descriptor with the Datasource reference, and still keep the rest of the auto-generated descriptor? Or do I have to substitute my own application.xml, and maintain it myself?

Comment: I just created a feature request here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MEAR-247 
Please vote for it in Jira if you're interested.